# Range query for selecting the "today"

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I am using watcher for selecting the today's records. Format of the timstamp is `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`. `now/d` rounds the time to beginning of the day. But the the following `from/to` values doen't seem to work. What's wrong the following query?

```
"filter": {
            "range": {
              "ingestion_timestamp": {
                "from": "now/d",
                "to": "now"
              }
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 0):

Range query has no from/to, it uses gt, gte, lt, lte to specify the range. See here for more info https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-query.html
Date range aggregation on the other hand uses from/to, see here
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-daterange-aggregation.html